# How to force downgrade a transitive dependency in dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

My app called A depends on nuget library B, and nuget library C version 1.1.1 using PackageReference in the csproj.

```
<PackageReference Include="B" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="C" Version="1.1.1" />
```

However, Library B depends on Library C >= 1.1.2.

```
<PackageReference Include="C" Version="1.1.2" />
```

I cannot change my app to run on C version 1.1.2 and I know B will work fine with C version 1.1.1.

How do I force my app A to run using C version 1.1.1? Specifically I need to remove compiler error CS1705. Previously in full framework I would have used binding redirects but I understand these are not available in dotnet core.

```
A
- B
- C (v = 1.1.1)


B
- C (v >= 1.1.2)
```

Comment: Why can't you change your app to use C v. 1.1.2? Libraries are backward compatible usually. If you aren't an author of B, it might be impossible

Comment: This example is an abstracted general case of a real problem, in which A is running in an managed environment where I don't have full control of the runtime (Azure Functions), and in which C v 1.1.2 is incompatible with A, and where I cannot change the source of B or C. Know it seems a bit arbitrary, but it does represent the general case of a real problem!

Comment: Well you will have to either upgrade to the later library, or remove it as a dependency of your app and write your own implementation of its features. Or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fix your CS1705 issue, but to have the exact version of 1.1.1 for package C then you'd use [Version Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges).

eg. `<PackageReference Include="C" Version="[1.1.1]" />`

You can also try to use [implicit versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#implicit-package-references) and let the build process decide that for you. You'd remove the `Version` attribute from the `<PackageReference />`

eg. `<PackageReference Include="C" />`

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/dependencies

Comment: Nice! After restarting VS, this notation is respected by the NuGet package manager. For example, `(4.5,5.0]` prevents it from suggesting an update to 5.0. Useful for compatibility or licensing issues. Not sure if the XML will get clobbered if you use the package manager to update to, say, 4.6.

Comment: @StackOverthrow You should be able to just unload and reload the specific project instead of restarting visual studio.

Comment: I just tested this out and while it does seem to allow the nuget restore to complete with only a warning you do still get build error CS1705